# My App crash when use intent: '' in Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sms, ngcordova

I'm using cordova-sms-plugin plugin.
I'm having some trouble with SMS plugin from ngCordova. If I send a message with the intent option set to 'INTENT', everything works fine, prompting the SMS application installed. But, when I set intent to ' ' (to use android's native SMS sender), my app crashes. Here's the code:

```
 $scope.sms = {};
    var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            intent: '' // send SMS with the default SMS app
        }
    };
    $scope.smsSend = function () {
        console.log($scope.sms.phno);
        console.log($scope.sms.msg);
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            $cordovaSms
                .send($scope.sms.phno, $scope.sms.msg, options)
                .then(function () {
                    // Success! SMS was sent
                    console.log('Success');
                }, function (error) {
                    // An error occurred
                    console.log(error);
                }); //then
        });
    };
```

### Testing OS : Marshmallow Android

Comment: You need to check that your app has permission to send SMS, as described in [the readme](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/blob/master/readme.md) (right above the FAQ). Marshmallow now requires certain permissions to be granted by the user at runtime. If your app doesn't have the permission when it sends, it'll crash with a `SecurityException`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But every time I get "hasPermission: false" in my console and when my app start its not ask me any Permission for SMS. Is it any possibility to ask permission  from user for SMS manually.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#runtime-permissions-cordova-android-500).

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for your help, I simply update my sms plugin( to v 1.10), now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`intent: ''` same as `intent: 'INTENT'`.

Try: **intent: 'blabla'**

```
var options = {
    replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
    android: {
        intent: 'blabla' // random word
    }
};
```

Use:

```
$scope.sms = {};
var options = {
    replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
    android: {
        intent: 'blabla' // random word
    }
};
$scope.smsSend = function () {
    console.log($scope.sms.phno);
    console.log($scope.sms.msg);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        $cordovaSms
            .send($scope.sms.phno, $scope.sms.msg, options)
            .then(function () {
                // Success! SMS was sent
                console.log('Success');
            }, function (error) {
                // An error occurred
                console.log(error);
            }); //then
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your Reply, I simply update my sms plugin( to v 1.10), now its working fine.